# Getting invalid SpanContext in mongo extension for java OpenTelemetry automatic instrumentation

Tags: open-telemetry

I am writing an extension of OpenTelemetry to input traceId as comment in mongo query. For this I have put an Advice on the `find` method in `com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection`. Inside the `Advice` when I call `spanContext.isValid()` it returns **false**, also spanId and traceId have all zeros in them.

`MongoQueryInstrumentation.java`

```
public class MongoQueryInstrumentation implements TypeInstrumentation {

  @Override
  public ElementMatcher<TypeDescription> typeMatcher() {
    return implementsInterface(named("com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection"));
  }

  public void transform(TypeTransformer transformer) {
    transformer.applyAdviceToMethod(
        named("find").and(takesArgument(0, Bson.class)).and(ElementMatchers.isPublic()),
        AdvicesFind.class.getName());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public static class AdvicesFind {

    @Advice.OnMethodExit(suppress = Throwable.class)
    public static void onExit(@Advice.Return(readOnly = false) FindIterable<?> result) {
      SpanContext spanContext = Java8BytecodeBridge.currentSpan().getSpanContext();
      System.out.println("traceId:" + spanContext.getTraceId());
      System.out.println("VALID :" + spanContext.isValid());
      result.comment(spanContext.getTraceId());
    }
  }
}
```

`MongoInstrumentationModule.java`

```
@AutoService(InstrumentationModule.class)
public final class MongoInstrumentationModule extends InstrumentationModule {
  public MongoInstrumentationModule() {
    super("mongo-ext", "mongo-4.0");
  }

  @Override
  public int order() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public ElementMatcher.Junction<ClassLoader> classLoaderMatcher() {
    return hasClassesNamed("com.mongodb.internal.async.SingleResultCallback");
  }

  @Override
  public List<TypeInstrumentation> typeInstrumentations() {
    return Collections.singletonList(new MongoQueryInstrumentation());
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
traceId:00000000000000000000000000000000
VALID :false
```

I am exporting the logs to zipkin, there `db.statement` is

```
{"find": "sampleCollection", "filter": {"title": "MongoDB"}, "comment": "00000000000000000000000000000000", "$db": "myDb", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "nOpqMCwHRWe2h+qmVEgGIQ==", "subType": "04"}}}}
```

I tried doing similar thing in JDBC by adding a comment containing traceId and spanId and there it worked as expected. There I patched `sendQueryString` method of `NativeProtocolInstrumentation`.
There `Java8BytecodeBridge.currentSpan().getSpanContext()` returned a valid spanId but in mongo it does not.